# How can I get the source code for the linux utility tail?

Tags: linux, tail, uclinux

this command is really very useful but where I can get the source code to see what is going on inside .

thanks .

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The tail utility is part of the coreutils on linux.

- Source tarball: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-7.4.tar.gz
- Source file: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c (original http [link](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c))

I've always found FreeBSD to have far clearer source code than the gnu utilities. So here's tail.c in the FreeBSD project:

- http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/usr.bin/tail/tail.c?view=markup

Comment: +1 for diversity, even though the original question was about linux utility.

Comment: I like how the linux version is several times longer than the BSD version.

Comment: The BSD version is shorter because the functions that do all the work aren't in that file. i.e.: follow().

Answer (score 1):

Poke around the uclinux site. Since they distributed the software, they are required to make the source available one way or another.

Or, you could read `man fseek` and guess at how it might be done.

NB-- See William's comments below, there are cases when you can't use seek.

Comment: tail does not use fseek.  If it did, it would not work on a stream (eg 'grep pat file | tail')

Comment: Hmm, never thought of that. Thanks. I have to think that it would still be faster when working with seekable input.

Comment: This is not exactly true. `tail` doesn't *always* use seek ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might find it an interesting exercise to write your own. The vast majority of the Unix command-line tools are a page or so of fairly straightforward C code.

To just look at the code, the GNU CoreUtils sources are easily found on gnu.org or your favorite Linux mirror site.

Comment: I wrote a fairly complete set of tools for MS-DOS back when Linux was in its infancy.  And while many are certainly straight forward, I would hesitate to say "a page' and wouldn't say a "vast majority".  **find** and **ls** for example, were considerably more complex.

Comment: The core of most of the tools generally *is* short. But the argument processing and corner case handling can be a pain.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have said "many" tools are short & simple. GNU tail has a lot of options, so it probably doesn't fit into the "simple" category. The version of tail that most people would use (i.e. tail -xxx file, or tail -f file) would be pretty simple.

Answer (score -2):

```c
/`*This example implements the option n of tail command.*/`

    #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <getopt.h>

    #define BUFF_SIZE 4096

    FILE *openFile(const char *filePath)
    {
      FILE *file;
      file= fopen(filePath, "r");
      if(file == NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file: %s\n",filePath);
        exit(errno);
      }
      return(file);
    }

    void printLine(FILE *file, off_t startline)
    {
      int fd;
      fd= fileno(file);
      int nread;
      char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
      lseek(fd,(startline + 1),SEEK_SET);
      while((nread= read(fd,buffer,BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
      {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, nread);
      }
    }

    void walkFile(FILE *file, long nlines)
    {
      off_t fposition;
      fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
      fposition= ftell(file);
      off_t index= fposition;
      off_t end= fposition;
      long countlines= 0;
      char cbyte;

      for(index; index >= 0; index --)
      {
        cbyte= fgetc(file);
        if (cbyte == '\n' && (end - index) > 1)
        {
          countlines ++;
          if(countlines == nlines)
          {
        break;
          }
         }
        fposition--;
        fseek(file,fposition,SEEK_SET);
      }
      printLine(file, fposition);
      fclose(file);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      FILE *file;
      file= openFile(argv[2]);
      walkFile(file, atol(argv[1]));
      return 0;
    }

    /*Note: take in mind that i not wrote code to parse input options and arguments, neither code to check if the lines number argument is really a number.*/
```