# Programmatically implementing tail -f in pure C

Tags: c, solaris, tail

I'm trying to implement a solution in pure C to monitor new entries made to log file that records a high volume of requests to a web service.

I would like something like tail -f, where a change in the log file results in my process getting the new changes instantly.

This needs to run on Solaris 10, unfortunately.

**I know this question has been asked and answered in other threads**, but none of the solutions acceptable for my situation

1) The solution must not require super user access in any way. As this is a enterprise production environment, no superuser access is available to me on this system, so I can't do something like install a driver.

2) The log file will be very large. Parsing it entirely, repeatedly for new changes is not acceptable.

It seems to me that if I can run tail -f as a non-privileged user, I should be able to do the same programmatically as the same user. I realize a nice hack would be to pipe the output from tail -f into my process, though I would like something cleaner.

Comment: Why not look at the source code for `tail`?

Comment: I actually don't have the source code for it, Solaris is closed source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439799/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-for-the-linux-utility-tail

Comment: Tail exists in Linux

Comment: `OpenSolars` was available but was closed by Oracle. There are some open source forks of it, see [OpenSolaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris)

Comment: Read the file in binary mode starting from the end one small chunck at a time, say a block worth looking for newline characters so as to determine the location of the last n lines. Store current file size and each time the file changes only read from that point on.

Comment: What is the reason not to use tail ?

Comment: The GNU coreutils implementation is available in source. ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/

Comment: And so is the (Open)Solaris one http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/tail/

Answer (score 2):

This is very straightforward - just read, and if you read zero bytes, wait for a specified time.  Just for illustration (open your own files and improve buffer and error handling to taste). I have edited this to show where error handling and seeking the last lines should occur, and fixed the position of the sleep().  This is by no means a complete example, just an indication of how things could be done.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NBUF 1024
int main()
{
  char buf[NBUF];
  ssize_t rcount, wcount;

  int fin = 0, fout = 1;  /* Or use open.  */
  /* Code to display the last 10 lines goes here.  */
  while (1)
    {
      while ((rcount = read (fin, buf, NBUF)) > 0)
    {
      wcount = write (fout, buf, rcount);
      if (wcount != rcount)
        {
          perror("write didn't work.");
          /* Handle error here, exit() or whatever.  */
        }
    }
      if (rcount == -1)
        {
           perror("Read didn_t work...");
           /* Handle error here, exit() or something else.  */
      sleep (1);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues here, AFAICS.  (1) You display the whole of the input, not just the last ten lines, and (2) You wait a second between read operations, which is fine if the input is less than one buffer-full per second, but not so hot if the input rate is higher (and 1 KiB/s is not a high speed input).  You only sleep if a read returns 0 bytes, I think.  If the read fails (`rcount == -1`), you should probably exit the loop.  The 'last ten lines' behaviour is the standard for `tail` and leads to interesting discussions when the file is gigabytes long.

Comment: @Johathan Leffler:  Your're right, this is not a comprehensive example, this just shows the principle how to show trailing output.  I didn't mean to write a complete tail(1) program, that is available from GNU coreutils.